What school of magic would the upper class want their children to learn quickly?
The world
In an Earth-like fantasy world at the start of its Industrial Revolution (with newly invented magitek instead of Steam engines), anyone can learn magic. Its study is time-consuming and exhausting, so few can actually dedicate themselves to it. The initial years are particularly tedious because you first need to develop your "6th sense".
However, there is a shortcut.
If a mother practices magic during her pregnancy, learning magic will be more intuitive for her child. He won't be more powerful than anyone else. It will only be easier for him to develop a "feel" for it.
If the mother focuses on a single school of magic, this effect will increase exponentially the more specific she goes. Her child may even be able to spontaneously produce small magical effects of the chosen school before receiving any education, allowing him to speedrun years of training. It won't slow nor speed his learning of other types of magic.
Question
Which type of magic would rich people want to teach their children extra-fast ?
If possible, it would be perfect if there was a reason strong enough so that they would want to be able to cast it themselves (without delegating to a full-fledged Mage), and would be ready to marry a little below their station just to be certain their children could use it.
And it would be even extra-more-perfect if this type of magic wouldn't be as useful to the lower classes.
Note : This world isn't fully polished, so the full list of magic schools isn't set in stone. You can assume the usuals are there : Necromancy, Enchantments, Elements-bending, etc.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

We've added a chatroom to hopefully help work on some questions that don't fit the usual model particularly well, if you want some further input head over to Story Tellers Corner with your question and we'll see if we can help.

Persuasion and Perception type schools
So, consider the current super-wealthy elite:
For almost every problem that they have in life, they have the money to hire someone to fix it for them:

Under Threat? Private security and bodyguards
Childcare? Nanny
Day-to-Day household chores? Staff, Maids, Servants, Cooks, Cleaners etc.
Scheduling? Personal Assistant
Health and Aging? Private Doctors and Personal Trainers etc.

etc.
So schools of magic that focus on elements of this are useless to them:

Attack and Defense Magic schools - Nope, they will hire an ex-special forces bodyguard skilled in those arts
Healing and longevity magic schools - Nope, they will hire a Doctor for that.

I could go on through all the lists - but you get the picture.
However, there is one thing that they cannot hire someone for - which is to make the big executive level calls.
Consider that you are a very powerful and wealthy person - you will have any N number of people trying to either take advantage of you (maliciously) or want to leverage your resources for their own ends (not necessarily maliciously).
The Internet is full of stories of people who got rich quick and then every Tom, Dick and Harry showed up with their cap in hand asking for Money.
This is where perception would be invaluable - to be able to discern the underlying motives of an individual. Perception helps with identifying potential threats - not necessarily physical threats (but that is included) but also things like strategic and political threats.
Think Tyrion in the Game of Thrones or Varys. Being aware of all the potential threats is a massive advantage.
For another example - being able to read through a complex legal contract and identify something that could be open to abuse or might pose a risk.
Persuasion, on the other hand, is similar, but slightly different - here, you are not worried about identifying the risk per se, but are concerned with being able to get people over to your side. Convincing people that it is in their best interest to do what you want and to not go against you means that a potential enemy or threat can be dealt with before the need for perception is required.
When doing complex high-level negotiating, whilst perception might spot a troublesome clause in a Legal contract Persuasion might mean that it never gets added in the first place.
To conclude - getting other people to do what you want or being able to see what someones true motivations are and being able to see potential threats are the key ones - everything else would be hired and or rented

Thank you for your answer, it fits with the need to have children be able to use this magic early since it would make them able to protect themselves from other people from a young age. But it could also bring the risk of making them little tyrants to their Nannies (which could be interesting in itself)

Divination
Without a doubt, divination is going to be the most useful tool for wealthy people to stay in power, with only empathetic/manipulation magic coming even close to it.
The biggest way rich people make money is not labour, but investment. Being able to predict the success of every potential business venture means that any wealth expenditures will approach as closely to optimal profitability as possible; understanding especially that this magic is not shared equally, the wealthy diviners would be able to grow their wealth orders of magnitude faster than a normal labourer or even a wealthy non-diviner. There is also the matter of any decisions; obviously, the rich and powerful will be under constant public scrutiny. Imagine being able to predict every single public relations risk, in addition to what politician would be best to fund, which ones not to trust who'll eventually side with the people. Divination basically enables maximum profitability and maximally effective preventative strategy for anything that could jar the wealthy and powerful from their lofty positions.
In our modern economy, divination becomes even more useful due to the existence of stock markets, which are highly based on speculation. Imagine the businessman that actually knows to buy all the apple stock he can because magic told him so. Another potentially interesting trait of this is that there is a certain incentive placed on destabilizing the economy. If you are a wealthy diviner, and the economy is unstable enough that most stocks are highly variable in value, you could easily sell at every peak and buy at every low, which I imagine would create several hundred percent returns over a fantastically short period of time, relative to what our stock investments look like today.
To be fair, I don't know that intentionally destabilizing the economy is sustainable. But the rich will always be able to weather that storm, and they might be so careful as to keep it from crossing that brink of collapse. They would want it unpredictable to the average person, but still alive. Which brings up the size of the population of wealthy diviners. I imagine that too many of them could naturally lead to a tragedy of the commons situation where they all take too much out of the economy and the whole thing collapses... so you might end up with a very insular, small class of ridiculously wealthy diviners, which deliberately kept their numbers small enough that their relatively predatory relationship to the economy and stock market didn't totally overload it. They'd of course have sublime public images and probably strings everywhere, but it could be interesting to see what kind of society would form.
In any case. The ability to predict the future, or the success of any venture, is far far more useful than any other, especially in the growing of wealth. Hands down.

I guess this depends on how powerful your divination magic is. It is one thing to find where the water source is for a village or when the rains will come, it is another to predict the stock market... That all said - damn this is a really strong answer!

Thanks! I would assume that even a weak effect ("good omen" vs "bad omen") is still more than worth it for any decision that involves a large investment. Once you have capital in a large enough quantity, any positive return is automatically going to be substantial relative to the average... and being able to get the better outcome consistently even if it doesn't approach complete perfection will similarly accumulate.

Empathic Magic

One of the main characters is a girl from a middle-class family sent to a magic academy by her parents in the hope it will allow her to snatch a rich husband later.

If the goal is to marry into a rich family, then these girls will specifically need to be able to control the affections of men and ward off the influences of competing young women.  By specializing in magic that lets her know what a prospective husband is thinking, she can appeal to the things he likes and avoid things that would make him not want to choose her.  It would also help her see past charades and false pretenses so that she could tell the difference between a man with a title and expensive things, and actual power, ambition, and sustainable wealth so that she does not get tricked into a marriage that does not suit her advancement in society.
Once she finds an ideal man, she could even implant thoughts and emotions into his head to make him fall in love with her, make him more devoted, giving her greater control over his wealth and resources, and making him more protective of her and her needs... after all, you don't have to be a good wife as long as you can make him believe that you are.
Once she has a wealthy and powerful husband, it will become her job to protect his mind and heart that it not be turned against her.  So, when other women come along, she will need to fortify his mind and affections against her.  She would also become his indispensable protector in his business dealings because she could use her power to ward him against the manipulation of others or by manipulating his business partners, supperiors, and clients to offer him better deals.
Lastly, once they have their own sons, it will be the role of the mother to safeguard her son's mind against the manipulation of similarly empathic women who are of a lower class, and unworthy of the son.  In this way, the aristocracy is mostly maintained because only young women powerful enough to overcome the wards a mother places on her son can command a man's affection thus proving herself a worthy wife. So while the main character may want to marry a prince, she will most likely only be powerful enough to compete amongst the other middle class empaths, but with the proper training of the school you've described, she may just be able to bag a lesser lord or a wealthy merchant's son.
Afterall, any man who gains his wealth by any school of magic other than empathic magic will need an empath to help him guard it.  And the only way a non-empath can command the loyalty of an empath is to marry her such that his wealth and success is also hers.

I can't imagine any nobility would let a magic school producing a continuous flow of mind-controlling parvenus be open for long... Also, their children would only learn psychic magic, so the whole aristocracy would quickly become a nest of mind-controlling upstarts. Which I'm not against! I'll just need to reflect a little more on how it would affect the story...

@BabikaBabaka The nobility will already engage in similar, but "better" schools just like how Ivy League graduates have no fear of state colleges producing better graduates than they are.

So, perhaps when the aristocracy is first established, it would be a nest of mind-controlling upstarts, but several generations in, it will be a nest of the world's most powerful and well educated mind-controlling savants in which these young middle class ladies could only sometimes infringe upon at the lowest noble echelons.

Magic Ivy League schools are a great idea! I really really like this answer, the only problem is that the story I'm trying to build is a sort of Fantasy Jane Austen Murder-Mystery.  With widespread mind-control added into the mix I'll need to completely rethink the mystery itself... I'll either use your answer or change the magic system to make psychic magic extremely rare, I can't decide yet  :(

@BabikaBabaka It's not just mind control, but also mind-defense.  Everyone in the room is experienced not in just planting thoughts, but defending against psychic suggestion and offering up fake thoughts to bait other psychics with.  Basically picture all the social jostling, trickery, and misdirection you already expect, but add a whole other dimension to it with all that is going unsaid.  Detectives would hate investigating the rich because those damn housewives can literally make their husbands forget they committed murder, or make someone else believe they did it themself.

The detectives themselves may be expert psychics, and mostly able to resist control, but are frustrated when faced with having to rely on physical evidence to solve the case.

One thing I like about this is that it emphasizes that like, oh if you want the magic heir, you have to take the risk of having a magic spouse. Which--if you're a wealthy nobleman who wants control of things--is likely a concerning proposition. There's a very ugly way that this could shake out in the themes of a book ('women are backstabbers never to be trusted'), but I think there's also a feminist reading of like, "the patriarchal society requires women's ability to have kids to perpetuate itself, but also fears/loathes them for it, leading to oppression etc".

@Kaia Yes, or there is a third way to take it: That the male and female role are necessary and interdependent counterparts to one another (Yin and Yang).  The man's magic is used to produce the wealth and power of the family, be it through conjuration, thaumaturgy, alchemy, or what not whereas the woman's magic is required to safeguard it. Without each other, they are both weak and vulnerable. It may even be necessary for cooperation to exist in the long term as keeping someone under your spell and protected from the spells of others might be mutually exclusive.

@Kaia This answer and its comments are eye-opening. At the start the young ladies school was only a part of a secondary character's past. I started with "An orphaned young woman tries to solve the murder of her best friend, and discovers who her own mother was through the magic she spontaneously manifests along the way" and now it looks like I'm going to have to think A LOT deeper about societal subjects... Also, my first idea for the Murder-Mystery answer will definitively have to be trashed   :-(

@BabikaBabaka I mean, you don't have to trash anything! It's your story!

@Kaia I really do... I have more interesting (if still very rough) new ideas, the old motive for the murder seems very uninspired now

@BabiBaba Hope I'm not pushing you too far back in your progress, but I'm glad I could inspire something deeper.


Wards against scrying and mind-altering spells.
Rich parents want to help their kids to become rich as well. Commercial rivals might hire mages to spy on their business decisions or even to force them into foolish choices. They could try to hire protective mages, but can they trust them? Better learn that for themselves.
Magic-detection spells.
Something to detect magically counterfeit coins, or to judge the quality of a Wizard's Staff. Again, the money involved would make it foolish to trust hired help.
Healing and anti-aging spells.
Money can buy trinkets, but can it buy health and long life? If lifesaving spells must be applied at once after an injury, one needs to have them along.


Thanks! Magic Wards could fit well with the "not as usefull for the lower classes" aspect. A peasant wouldn't have as much to hide from spies (same for a middle-class person to a lesser extent)

Culturally dependent
Unfortunately there is no single answer. We can see this from our real world. Without magic the same choices can be made. What would be best to learn for a woman to snatch a rich husband? Cooking? Sometimes important, but with others servants can do this. Entertainment of the flesh? In some cultures the men could feast on anything moving, so sating such desires would not be of importance. Etiquette? Might be learned from birth or such ballers they do not need to adhere to such rules. It is important in some cultures, and useless to others.
The same applies to magic schools. My first reaction would be that healing is important to keep the husband, and possibly themselves, alive as long as possible. But they can use a full fledged mage for that. Food? Full mage. Necromancy? Enchantments? Shape-shifting? Each can be done better by a full mage and might be viewed as beneath them.
This gives you freedom in your story. Even from village to village this can change, putting the emphasis on the local customs. It could even be that you just need to "have studied magic". Not unlike some things require no further certification than "studied at a university". Simply the prestige is enough. Whether you animate hedgehogs, can arrange magical flowers or fly doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things.

Hi! I'm still trying to define the curriculum of the magical academy. These women would learn types of magic that would be usefull for their children to use, not themselves. They won't become powerful witches, and just want to make sure their highborn children can learn this magic fast. So the real question is "What magic would the Nobility want to be able to use themselves?"

Priority should be offense and defense magic. Get your enemies before they get you and intimidate underlings who might want to shortcut to your riches.
The rest is just gravy.
This is why nobles taught their kids to fight in every ancient society. You have to protect what is yours and you inherit enemies and if you're an easy target you gain more very quickly.
Main dangers are your own family, other nobles and your friends & retinue. Normal foot soldiers have a more black and white set of enemies who might not even be targeting them specifically. So your personal offense and defense should be of paramount importance.

Nobles also tend to delegate most of the actual fighting to soldiers and bodyguards... If possible, do you think there is a more specific kind of magical offense or defense that aristocrats would want to use themselves ? Bonus point if it wouldn't be of much use to common foot-soldiers

They'll delegate all of the fighting if possible. Personal offense and defense is the priority. Against assassination etc, or people sneaking up on them. Not battle offense and defense, they would have professionals for that, just as they have captains and generals.

It depends on the level of nobility.  The lower nobility were the captains, and generals; so, these may be valuable skills for knights... but I don't see why the women of the nobility would be thus trained.  Even when you allow magic to set aside the differences in physical traits, men tend to be more aggressive, tactically minded, and internalize trauma differently in a way that would typically make them better battle mages.  Also, you want to keep your women off the battlefield to replace your losses. Civilizations that encourage women be soldiers tend to suffer population collapses.

@Nosajimiki life could be just as ruthless and dangerous for noblewomen. I never mentioned women on battlefields, I specifically said 'personal' offense & defence..

Why wouldn't priority go to economics-based magic? As much as the rich want security, what they really want is to be rich. You can always hire someone to protect you.

@JBH and if the person you hired gets bribed or killed? You're already rich, you can and do hire people to make you richer. But they may decide to enrich themselves.

@JBH You're thinking from a modern point of view. Feudal societies never ever worked that way, because the ability to hire troops was a direct threat to the nobility. Rich commoners were typically either coopted into the nobility through marriage, taxed heavily, or executed or exiled for variously invalid reasons.

@Graham You actually believe that there's one objective "best answer" that's independent of character choices and story circumstances? My POV is irrelevant and we're not talking about the casually rich - this world element would turn all the non-magic users into slaves (review Earth history for examples of the too wealthy enslaving the too poor).

@Kilisi See above.

@JBH you rarely make sense to me.... feel free to downvote or whatever

If you look at our world for some examples, usually certain sports and activities were seen as popular and other aristocratic.
Popular ones were usually:

group activities so that more people could enjoy it at the same time, optimizing the available resources
could be done with limited resources, for example making a ball with an inflated bladder or with rags.

Aristocratic ones instead were usually:

individual activities
required specialized and therefore expensive equipment

For example compare popular football with aristocratic tennis, or commoners' knives fighting vs the more aristocratic sword fighting, or how having a tanned complexion was frowned upon aristocrats until not too long ago.
If you want to use the same in your case, you have to see which values and believes are considered popular and which aristocratic, and from there draw a line between which magic is popular and which aristocratic.

Thank you for your answer!! The "expensive equipment" part is super interesting. I could make it so using some types of powerful and prestigious artifacts can only be done if you are able to cast a very specific type of magic. That way, it would be super-important for rich families with ancestral magical artifacts to be able to use them, and also be useless for commoners! :D
